# Best client interface for working with clickhouse dictionaries in queries

Tags: dictionary, client, clickhouse

I am currently exploring the possibility of implementing a datawarehouse with corresponding BI tools with Clickhouse. Typically, dimensional data modeling leads to many joins in queries, which should be avoided in order to optimize performance. Clickhouse recommends using dictionaries instead. So far, so good. Now I wonder, how the BI client application will work with these dictionaries. Obviously, this question depends on the interface that is used for communication between the client and clickhouse (especially for making analytical queries). Since clickhouse-specific dictionaries are not supported by JDCB/ODBC, these options are out of question - am I right? Which interface is the best option for this purpose?

Comment: I think you need to take some BI tool (for example, Tableau) and check base use-cases. Look at this article [tableau with clickhouse](https://altinity.com/blog/2018/7/19/tableau-with-clickhouse).

Comment: + Tableau related info: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+tableau

Comment: in the latest CH you can create dictionaries by DML command `create dictionary` in this case a dictionary has a table representation and looks like usual table. And there is an optimization which rewrites joins with such tables to a dictionary lookups https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/10133

Comment: *has a table representation (automatically).

you can create such Engine=Dictionary tables manually if you use/prefer XML

Comment: @DennyCrane Does this mean that I can simply use the JOIN syntax and CH automatically replaces the JOIN with dictionary lookups, if available?

Comment: Yes it does. Check with your CH version. It's a new feature.